# Should I use time as part of a composite key or create a new primary key?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in my database that consists of two foreign keys, which together are still not unique, but adding a time/date to them would make them unique. Is it a good idea to use those three columns together as the primary key or should I just create a new column and use a separate primary key?

Comment: I think it's a better idea to use a surrogate key generated by the database as the primary key in this case.

Comment: How would a time/date make it unique?  Like Leo said, add a generated key.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards but I'm new to database design so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @ForguesR yeah, it seems a little more obvious now, I'm going to add a separate column for a primary key.

Comment: If you don't have columns that can make up a primary key in the first place, what is a surrogate id a surrogate *for*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a timestamp to artificially create a composite primary key from other 2 columns is not a good idea IMO because you can have HW fast enough to generate two identical composite keys in your database.

Instead, you may check your database for a surrogate key generator (usually some sort of sequence) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

NO:  adding a `time based value to build a primary key can not valid as you can understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804532/simultaneous-mysql-insertions-in-the-same-table-how-to).

It is better to create a primary key of its own to your table.